# Define number of cycles - Benchmark.js

Tags: javascript, benchmark.js

I am trying to execute a sample performance benchmark using Benchmark.js.
Here is what I have wrote:

```
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');
var arr = []
benchmark = new Benchmark('testPerf',function(){
    arr.push(1000);
},
{
    delay: 0,
    initCount: 1,
    minSamples: 1000,
    onComplete : function(){ console.log(this);},
    onCycle: function(){}
});
benchmark.run();
```

Now like we do in JUnitBenchmarks:

```
@BenchmarkOptions(clock = Clock.NANO_TIME, callgc = true, benchmarkRounds = 10, warmupRounds = 1)
```

Here also I want to declare `benchmarkRounds` and `warmupRounds` count in benchmarkjs. I think `warmupRounds` maps to `initCount`? And how to set exact number of cycles/benchmark iteration?

Or if we have some other good JavaScript library that can handle it would work too.

Comment: Benchmarking in JavaScript using a fixed iteration count is [problematic](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/bulletproof-javascript-benchmarks/), so Benchmark.js does not allow that option. Instead, it runs tests over and over again [until results can be considered reasonably accurate](http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/12/11/benchmarkjs.html).

Comment: @approxiblue Please post this comment as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using fixed iteration counts in JavaScript benchmarks is risky: [we might get zero-time results eventually](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/bulletproof-javascript-benchmarks/), as browsers become faster.

Benchmark.js does not allow setting the number of rounds/iterations in advance. Instead it runs tests over and over again until results can be considered reasonably accurate. You should check out the [code reading by Monsur Hossain](http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/12/11/benchmarkjs.html). Some highlights from the article:

- A cycle in Benchmark.js consists of set-up, tear-down, and multiple iterations of the actual test.
- Benchmark.js starts with the **analysis phase**: run a few cycles to find the optimal number of iterations (finish the test as fast as possible while collecting enough samples to generate accurate results).
- The number of cycles run during analysis is saved in [`Benchmark.prototype.cycles`](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#prototype_cycles).
- Knowing the optimal number of iterations, Benchmark.js begins the **sampling phase**: runs the tests and actually stores the results.
- [`Benchmark.prototype.stats.sample`](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#stats_sample) is an array of results from each cycle during sampling.
- [`Benchmark.prototype.count`](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#prototype_count) is the number of iterations during sampling.

Answer (score 5):

Looking over the docs at:

http://benchmarkjs.com/docs

Sounds like you are correct

1. warmupRounds => initCount (http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#options_initCount)
2. cycles => http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#prototype_cycles

Comment: A cycle consists of set-up, tear-down, and multiple iterations of the test. A cycle is _not_ a single iteration of the test, as seems to be the case in [JUnitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks-tutorial.html).

Comment: Cycles don't work as expected. I have defined `cycles`: 10 but function is executed 73 times. Looks like @approxiblue is correct

Answer (score 4):

Regardless if it's a good idea, if you set `minTime` and `maxTime` to some negative values then `minSamples` and `initCount` will be left as the only criteria and they will correspond to #cycles and warmup iterations run at each cycle. So the test function will be executed (`initCount`+1) * `minSamples` times. At least that's what my experiments show.

```
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');
var counter = 0;
Benchmark('counting', {
  'fn': function() { ++counter; },
  minSamples: 3,
  initCount: 1,
  minTime: -Infinity,
  maxTime: -Infinity,
  onCycle: function () { console.log('[onCycle] counter: ' + counter); },
  onComplete : function(){ console.log('mean: ' + this.stats.mean);},
}).run();
```

gives me with benchmark.js 2.1.0:

```
$ node count.js
[onCycle] counter: 2
[onCycle] counter: 4
[onCycle] counter: 6
mean: 0.0000034683333333333333
```